# Сохранить часть изображения в файл

Tags: awt, java

Как сохранить часть изображения в файл?

```
  File file = new File(filename);
  image = ImageIO.read(file);
  final Graphics g = image.getGraphics().create(85, 20, 773, 1010);
  // и вот этот g и надо сохранить в какой-нибудь другой файл
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Graphics` - это графический контекст, его нельзя сохранить. Сохраняется битмап/имидж, который создается в этом контексте.

Пример [фтыкать здесь](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.imageio/Graphic2File.html)